# Mute PAM8302 amp with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python

I'm using a PAM8302 amplifier with a Raspberry Pi Zero W and it's working great. However, I'd like to start the amp muted and then unmute it from a Python script. Per documentation, PAM8302 goes into shutdown when the shutdown pin is connected to ground and I verified that by connecting it to RPi's ground. I tried connecting the shutdown pin to a GPIO pin that starts low and one that starts high (measured ~0V and 3.3V respectively), and neither mutes the amp. If I hook it up to ground it mutes, but I can't unmute it, since ground pins aren't controllable. Is there a way I can have programmatic control over the mute function? The only way I can think of is using a relay, but I'd rather avoid it if at all possible.

Thanks!

Comment: `GPIO pin that starts low` .... are you sure that it starts low?

Comment: I measured the voltage between the pin and ground and it was hovering around 0.3mv

Comment: that measurement is taken with the PAM8302 connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All GPIO pins start as inputs by default. This is normal for most similar devices.

NONE start as outputs, low or high, although the input pins may have a pull-up or pull-down.

The Device Tree can be used to change pin assignments shortly after boot. This is often used to enable the serial interface etc.

To configure a pin as output you need an appropriate Device Tree overlay.

The [gpio config](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=117&p=1290447#p1290447) can be used to set the  configuring pins at "boot" time - actually some short time after boot.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll give it a go and report the result.

Comment: It worked!! I edited /boot/config.txt and added `gpio=26=op,dl` where 26 is the GPIO pin connected to the amp's shutdown pin. It mutes it in less than a second after power is supplied to the board. Thank you for your help!